# Logging wrapper - log4j

Tags: log4j, wrapper

I have a requirement to do a wrapper interface so that you can switch between different kind of logging mechanisms without changing the code. So I have my own info(String message) method inside a Wrapper class, like:

public void info( Object message )
    {
        if ( isInfoEnabled() )
        {
            logger.info( message );
        }
    }

It works as expected except that when logging it does not show the class and line of the from where I am logging, but those from the Wrapper class.
Can you please help...

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to use [Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J)](http://www.slf4j.org/) instead of your own wrapper. From its website:

> The Simple Logging Facade for Java or (SLF4J) serves as a simple facade or abstraction for various logging frameworks, e.g. java.util.logging, log4j and logback, allowing the end user to plug in the desired logging framework at deployment time.

This is a moderner and preferred<sup>1</sup> alternative to Jakarta Commons Logging (JCL). I recommend to read [this article](http://articles.qos.ch/thinkAgain.html?) for a detailed analysis but the short version is that SLF4J doesn't suffer from the class loader problems or memory leaks observed with JCL. The author of Commons Logging himself [admits it](http://radio-weblogs.com/0122027/2003/08/15.html).

In case you wonder, SLF4J has been written by Ceki Gülcü which is the author of Log4J (and now works on Logback, the successor of Log4J). So this guy know a thing or two about logging and there are some chances "his" wrapper is better than mine.

In other words, there is IMHO just no point at creating a wrapper in 2010 when a nice and good one already exists.

<sup>1</sup> Please, don't use Spring as counter example, Spring is a bad counter example (see [SPR-5327](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5327)).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Although I understand very well your point of view, my requirement is very specific and I have to have my own logger - this is not really a production application. So, could someone please, answer specifically to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's already a wrapper interface around various logging implementations: [Apache Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/). Have you tried using that instead?

Answer (score 1):

So, to solve my specific requirement, here is it what should be done...

```
public class Log4jWrapper implements ILogger
```

{
    private Logger logger;

```
/**
 * The name of this wrapper class
 */
static final String FQCN = Log4jWrapper.class.getName();

/**
 * Constructor which returns the root content
 */
public Log4jWrapper()
{
    logger = Logger.getRootLogger();
}

/**
 * Creates a {@link Logger} object
 * 
 * @param clazz name reference for this category to create
 */
public Log4jWrapper( Class<?> clazz )
{
    logger = Logger.getLogger( clazz );
}

/**
 * Log an debug message
 * 
 * @param msg the message
 */
public void debug( Object msg )
{
    if ( isDebugEnabled() )
    {
        logger.log( FQCN, Level.DEBUG, msg, null );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you wrap log4j.  You pass `log()` the name of your wrapper class.

```
class YourLog4jWrapper {

  Logger _base = Logger.getLogger(/*....*/);

  private void log(Object msg) {
    _base.log(YourLog4jWrapper.class.getName(), Priority.INFO, msg, null);
  }

}
```